# Solr - search word immediately followed by partial match (with wildcard)

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr index filled with documents, with a field named *issuer*.
There is a document with issuer=*first issuer*.

I'm trying to implement matching of two consequent words. The first word needs to match completely, the second needs to match partially.

What I am trying to achieve is:

- I search for something like: `issuer:first\ iss*`
- I expect it to match "**first iss** uer"

I tried the following solutions but none is working:

```
issuer:first\ iss*       -> returns nothing
issuer:"first iss"*      -> returns everything
issuer:(first iss*)      -> also returns "issuer first"
```

Does anybody have a clue on how to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to add a shiringle filter based field type to your schema. Below is a simple definition:

```
<fieldtype name="shingle">
  <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

You then add another field with this type as shown below:

```
<field name="issuer_sh" type="shingle" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

At query time, you can issue the following query:

```
issuer_sh:"first iss*"
```

The shingleFilter creates n-gram tokens from your text. For instance, if the issuer field contains "first issue", then Solr will create and index the following tokens:

```
first  
issue
first issue
```

Comment: I see, this is truly interesting! I take it will be more performant than creating a copy field with a `KeywordTokenizer`, right?

Comment: They are the same. If you are using the field to query documents and relevance of documents using the issuer field is not important, then you should go with **KeywordTokenzier**. A better solution is using **EdgeNGramFilterFactory** with **KeywordTokenizer**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't search with wildcards in phrase queries. Without changing how you are indexing (see @ameertawfik's answer), the standard query parser doesn't provide a good way to do this. You can, however, use the [surround query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser) to search using spans. This query would then look like:

```
1N(first, iss*)
```

Keep in mind, surround query parser does not analyze, so `1N(first, iss*)` and `1N(First, iss*)` will not find the same results.

You could also construct this query using lucene's SpanQueries directly, of course, like:

```
SpanQuery[] queries = new SpanQuery[2];
queries[0] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("issuer","first"));
queries[1] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new PrefixQuery(new Term("issuer","iss")));
Query finalQuery = new SpanNearQuery(queries, 0, true);
```

Comment: However in this case I have to predict beforetimes that `iss` is going to stand for `issuer`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: No,  in the manually constructed spanqueries, "issuer" is the field name,  not a search term.

Comment: Yes, forget it, I got it right on the second pass... ;-)